# Changing the drop-down list after entering the product code with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have stored products in my database. I want to send an ajax request to the server as soon as the user enters the product code, and the sizes related to that product code will be taken for me and displayed in the drop-down list.

I have written the following code for this, the request is correctly sent to the server and the size is taken for me.

My problem is that Responso doesn't appear in the dropdown list for me

html code

```
<div class="form-group  col-md-2">
<label>productCode</label>
<input type="text"  class="form-control" id="productCode">
</div>
<div class="form-group  col-md-2">
<label>productSize</label>
<select  id="productSize" class="form-control">
                                        
</select>
</div>
```

ajax code

```
$('#productCode').keyup(function () {
           var productId = this.value;
           $.ajax({
               method:'post',
               url:'<?= baseUrl() ?>/panel/getSizeProduct',
               data:{
                'productId':productId
            },
               success:function(msg) {
                   $('#productSize').html(msg);

               }
           })
       });
```

my controller

```
public function getSizeProduct()
    {
        $productId = post('productId');
        $records = PanelModel::getSizeByProductId($productId);
        foreach($records as $record) {
            echo '  <option value='.$record['productSize'].'>'.$record['productSize'].'</option>';
        }
    }
```

my model

```
public static function getSizeByProductId($productCode)
     {
      $db = Db::getInstance();
      $records = $db->query("SELECT productSize FROM s_product WHERE productCode=:productCode", array(
         'productCode' => $productCode,
      ));
      return $records;
     }
```

updated

When inspecting the element the values ​​are placed correctly but nothing is displayed for me in the ui part

Comment: What was your problem here ?

Comment: @KayisRahman It is not placed in the dropdown list for me

Comment: @KayisRahman But my problem is not with sending the request, the request is sent correctly, my problem is in placing it in the drop-down list

Comment: Could you please console.log() msg variable and check the response is coming as expected

Comment: Check the network request. Is the status code 200? In success, put an alert (msg). Does it display the correct value?

Comment: Seems okay to me. Check whether there are some errors or warnings placed in your log.

Comment: @MostafaNZ Yes, my status code is 200 and the sizes related to me are displayed in the response section

Comment: @KayisRahman in console.log <option value=60120>60120</option>

Comment: Your code is working for me. Make sure the javascript code is executed after the HTML DOMs get populated. 

Wrap value attr with a double-quote, I don't think it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem, I will leave my method to solve this problem, maybe it will help other friends

```
$('#productSize').selectpicker('refresh');
```